# Redshift graph of Type Ia supernova: Two case

Tags: cosmology, redshift, supernova

The redshift graph obtained from a well-known supernova study appears in two cases in Google search.

[image]
[image]

When I find the relevant data, regardless of whether the y-axis is set to distance or grade, the shape of the graph represents a deviation in a straight line or a deviation in a curve. How are the equations of the two graphs different? Is it the difference between representing it in the form of a logarithmic function or a linear function? I want to know the specific formula.

Answer (score 1):

In both of your graphs, the y-axis is the distance modulus defined below ($d_L$ is the luminosity distance).
\begin{equation}
\mu = m-M = 25 + 5\log d_L ; \ d_L = c(1+z)\int_0^z \frac{dz'}{H(z')}
\end{equation}

This explains why the slope changes as you go to the right in the second plot. This is not the case in the first one because for small redshifts, we have a linear plot (for much shorter distances we could use simple parallax formula as well).